# R shiny: how to build a list of input elements and then return them as a single element for rendering in the UI?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to generate a bank of R shiny slider inputs like:

```
label1:
<-------------slider1------------->
label2:
<-------------slider2------------->
```

For some variable number of inputs. However, I need to return all the generated elements as a single element or component for use in a higher level UI function, so I'm thinking of maybe wrapping the whole thing in a div(). I'm stuck at this point:

```
lapply(
    listOfSliderLabels, function(sliderLabel){
    #build a new slider: sliderInput(...)
    #how do I add this new slider to something like a div, and return the div?
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you question, but it sounds you may need to build a [Shiny module](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/#modules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`do.call`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html) is great for programmatically building inputs. Here's an example that uses it with `lapply` to build slider inputs from a list of args:

```
sliderInputData <- list(
  list(inputId = "slider1", label = "slider1", min = 1, max = 5, value = 3),
  list(inputId = "slider2", label = "slider2", min = 2, max = 5, value = 4),
  list(inputId = "slider3", label = "slider3", min = 3, max = 5, value = 5)
)

buildSliderInputs <- function(inputData) {
  inputs <- lapply(inputData, function(args) {
    do.call(sliderInput, args)
  })

  do.call(div, inputs)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  buildSliderInputs(sliderInputData)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `do.call(div, inputs)`  - brilliant!! Didn't know you could do that. thanks!